# Are the "gentlease" and "sensitive" infant formulas anything more than sugar water?

Tags: infant, formula

The primary ingredient for the regular infant formula is "nonfat milk". The primary ingredient for the "gentlease" and "sensitive" formulas is "corn syrup". Seems to me we should be going with the regular infant formula even if that means a little gas. Am I wrong for thinking milk is better than corn syrup?

Comment: There's not much nutrition in corn syrup.

Comment: I am neither a pediatrician nor a dietician, but I believe most folks would say that corn syrup is a bad thing for most anyone...so can't imagine giving it to babies. (But yea, definitely consult your pediatrician)

Comment: It's just interesting because the back of the container talk about how many carbs and protein and vitamins and it's all about the same between the two.  It just sucks that there is so much "marketing" on the packaging as if it's no big deal to switch. I mean, who WOULDN'T want to try the one that is easier on their baby?

Answer (score 1):

Note that nonfat milk could reasonably be called protein-fortified sugar water.  The [nutritiondata entry for milk](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/139/2) indicates that one cup of nonfat milk is 12g sugar, 8g protein, 222g water (and 3g other).  Compare the nutrition information for [Gentlease](http://www.enfamil.com/app/iwp/enf12/product.do?dm=enf&id=/Consumer_Home3/FeedingSolutions/EnfamilGentleaseLIPIL2&iwpst=B2C&ls=0&cm_mmc=Digitas-SEM-_-Google-Solutions-_-Gentlease-_-gentlease&csred=1&r=3514760267) versus [regular Enfamil](http://www.enfamil.com/app/iwp/enf12/product.do?dm=enf&id=/Consumer_Home3/Infants/EnfamilPremiumInfant&iwpst=B2C&ls=0&csred=1&r=3514760338) and you'll find that they are quite similar.  My experience is that formulas are very similar in terms of nutrition.  So, if I were you, I'd go with whatever formula works best for your baby that fits within your budget.

Comment: What "works best for your baby" is really hard to determine. I mean, just because she's fussy one day doesn't mean it's the formula, you know? There is no science in parenting.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between sugar and  more complex carbs like lactose. See http://www.foodreactions.org/intolerance/lactose/absorption.html for an in-depth explanation.

Lactose will be converted to only glucose, and this will only happen in the small intestine, at a certain rate. Corn syrup however is glucose + fructose, which will hit the blood as soon as it can. Fructose has several issues, see http://high-fat-nutrition.blogspot.com/2012/05/on-glut5.html for some background (sorry not really an overview link but better than the Lustig lecture).

So the blood sugar response between the two types will be different, with the corn syrup one unlike what babies will experience on mothers milk, and the fructose in corn syrup may cause  stress on the baby's body, it is a sugar babies are normally not exposed to until they eat fruit and even then not in very high volume.

Add to that the possible antinutrients that are in corn and in the syrup, and corn syrup becomes a cheap but in my eyes criminal choice.

Mind you I think http://www.westonaprice.org/childrens-health/recipes-for-homemade-baby-formula is the best formula so I'm probably biased :)

Comment: Homemade sounds like a compelling option. Right now my wife pumps and we only supplement with formula (currently, the "sensitive" one, mostly because it's "easier on the baby" according to marketing . . I hate the marketing).

Comment: Okay, I just read the instructions for homemade and it seems more complicated than making beer. Not a good sign.

Comment: Right, and to be honest I never made it, but I wish I could. The misses and I don't see eye-to-eye on this. So I resorted to using the formula with the least allergens ignoring dairy (so no wheat, soy, maize or egg white), with a near 1:1 balance of the long Omega 3 and 6 fats (look at AA and DHA/EPA numbers) and only lactose for sugars, and a sensible vitamin/mineral mix. It takes a lot of box peering and some research but it's replacing something immensely complicated and optimized. As soon as the baby is old enough she'll be getting real foods from good sources.